# Automatic generation of LDFLAGS, CPPFLAGS and other from error messages

Tags: compiling, make, header-file

While integration, merging, porting and cross-compilation of various projects I encounter many errors caused by missing headers or undefined symbols. Then I manually search headers and libraries to determine the correct options to add to LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to solve the errors. Usually it is rather routine procedure.

Is there a tool capable of automatically generating proper LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS options in this way?

I know about `pkg-config` but it only works with pre-configured projects: the projects need to provide a `.pc` file, and the user needs to know about them. I am looking for solutions in situations where `pkg-config` can't help.

My own project, [`errors_resolver`](https://github.com/makelinux/errors_resolver), is a Python script which analyzes various compilation and system errors and helps to solve them.

Comment: I hope my edit is coherent with what you're looking for, and why `pkg-config` isn't the answer...

Comment: pkg-config requires to know needed package. I am trying to analyze error messages and automatically find solution.

Answer (score 7):

The common approach is to use [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/). For exemple, to link against GLib 2,

```
pkg-config --libs glib-2.0
```

will print the appropriate linker flags, and

```
pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
```

will print the appropriate preprocessor flags. That does require that the development files for GLib are installed...

Comment: Thank you. Actually I mean more wide and generic solution. I edit the question.

Comment: pkg-config can also provide CPPFLAGS.

Comment: I mean even more generic solution, where pkg-config don't help.
I look also for proper -I and -L options (include and lib path). 
Here is my attempt to solve the problem: https://github.com/makelinux/errors_resolver

Comment: `pkg-config` does provide `-I` and `-L` options when necessary...

Comment: But pkg-config dos't help for projects where it is not configured.